# Consuming WCF webservice using STS authentication token

Tags: asp.net, claims-based-identity, sts-securitytokenservice

I am looking for something that I haven't been able to find out as yet.. Can you please tell me that if there's a way that I can use, the token returned by the STS, with a claims aware WCF webservice. Like for now I am trying to do it I am able to create a claims aware WCF service but when i try to call it's function in the Relying party (which has been authenticated by the STS) its unable to consume it. It gives an error {"The incoming policy could not be validated. For more information, please see the event log."}

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer to my question. Now when it comes to consuming a claims aware webservice we should have an Active STS for its authentication. There are two kinds of Secure Token Services one is Active and other is passive. Active is used to authenticate Webservices and Passive is used for websites authentication.